# select multiple objects from list based on a where condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am have a list of type PriceDetails (shown below). I also have a list which can contain multiple PriceDetails objects with the same ISIN. For a given ISIN I  would like to select all the PriceDetails object with that ISIN.

I thought something like below would work but it doesn't even compile.

**Class**

```
class PriceDetails
{
     string ISIN;
     string Sedol;
     double Price;
     string Source;
}
```

**Code**

```
    List<PriceDetails> secPrices = (from p in pList
                                    where p.ISIN == someISIN
                                    select secPrices).ToList();
```

**Error message**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProg.PriceDetails> to System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProg.PriceDetails>
```

Comment: It would be better if you've shown compiler error message to prevent us from guessing. For example, it can tell you that your `PriceDetails` fields are unaccessible since they are private (at least at the example code you've shown).

Comment: sorry forgot to write it, now included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select `p` instead of `secPrices`:

```
List<PriceDetails> secPrices = (from p in pList
                                where p.ISIN == someISIN
                                select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your select is wrong, try that:

```
 var secPrices = (from p in pList
                                    where p.ISIN == someISIN
                                    select p).ToList();
```